# Make a new column picking values from a data frame depending on the values in the same data frame in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I got the data frame

```
   Z1  Z2  Z3  Z4
   AB  XX  1   100  
   BA  YY  2   200
   AB  YY  1   200
   BA  XX  2   100
```

And I want to make a new column picking Z1 or Z2 depending on the values in Z3 and Z4.

The conditions are if Z3= h1 or Z4=h10 then Z5 is Z1 else Z5=Z1; the table should look like this:

```
   Z1  Z2  Z3  Z4  Z5
   AB  XX  h1  h10 AB  
   BA  YY  h2  h20 YY
   AB  YY  h1  h20 AB
   BA  XX  h2  h10 BA
```

To achieve this I do:

```
df = within(df,{
 Z5 == ifelse(df$Z3 == "h1" | df$Z4 == "h10", df$Z1,df$Z2)
})
```

When I do this I get no values in df$Z5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ifelse` directly:

```
df$Z5 <- ifelse(df$Z3 == "h1" | df$Z4 == "h10", df$Z1, df$Z2)
df

  Z1 Z2 Z3  Z4 Z5
1 AB XX h1 h10 AB
2 BA YY h2 h20 YY
3 AB YY h1 h20 AB
4 BA XX h2 h10 BA
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Z1=c("AB", "BA", "AB", "BA"),
                 Z2=c("XX", "YY", "YY", "XX"),
                 Z3=c("h1","h2","h1","h2"),
                 Z4=c("h10","h20","h20","h10"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: @user2974951 I think your data has some problem, check my answer where the logic is working.

Comment: My bad, you were quicker than me ^^ (similar answer deleted).

Comment: Thank you. This difference between characters and factors is very annoying.

Comment: Most of the time, you can probably get away with just sticking with the character type rather than the factor type.

Comment: It would be much easier if the defult in R would be characters.

Comment: @sfetan Coming soon https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/